# How to write colored text in log file with python

Tags: python, logging

I have a log file with name LogFile.log
I write in this file different logs using the way of writing into a file:

```
logfile = open(LogFile.log, 'a')
logFile.write("<< INFO >> ")
```

How can I write my log with different colors(e.g. red for errors, green for info, orange for debug)?

I am using Python 2.5 as it is fully compatible with another tool I am using.

Answer (score 1):

You can write colored lines to a terminal using ANSI color codes (see [Printing to STDOUT and log file while removing ANSI color codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893650/printing-to-stdout-and-log-file-while-removing-ansi-color-codes)), but you cannot write colored lines to a file.

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think you can't output colored Messages to a utf-8 log file.

As mentioned before you could use colored CLI or try to implement an own logger which outputs log messages to html for example. Html would be able to realize coloring.

Comment: This is rephrasing a previous answer without providing any more information. In the future, if you want to comment on an existing answer, please do that instead.

Answer (score -4):

you can integrate color with python logging module

```
BLACK, RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE = range(8)

#The background is set with 40 plus the number of the color, and the foreground with 30

#These are the sequences need to get colored ouput
RESET_SEQ = "\033[0m"
COLOR_SEQ = "\033[1;%dm"
BOLD_SEQ = "\033[1m"

def formatter_message(message, use_color = True):
    if use_color:
        message = message.replace("$RESET", RESET_SEQ).replace("$BOLD", BOLD_SEQ)
    else:
        message = message.replace("$RESET", "").replace("$BOLD", "")
    return message

COLORS = {
    'WARNING': YELLOW,
    'INFO': WHITE,
    'DEBUG': BLUE,
    'CRITICAL': YELLOW,
    'ERROR': RED
}

class ColoredFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, msg, use_color = True):
        logging.Formatter.__init__(self, msg)
        self.use_color = use_color

    def format(self, record):
        levelname = record.levelname
        if self.use_color and levelname in COLORS:
            levelname_color = COLOR_SEQ % (30 + COLORS[levelname]) + levelname + RESET_SEQ
            record.levelname = levelname_color
        return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
```

if you want to use this thing, then create your own logger

```
# Custom logger class with multiple destinations
class ColoredLogger(logging.Logger):
    FORMAT = "[$BOLD%(name)-20s$RESET][%(levelname)-18s]  %(message)s ($BOLD%(filename)s$RESET:%(lineno)d)"
    COLOR_FORMAT = formatter_message(FORMAT, True)
    def __init__(self, name):
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, name, logging.DEBUG)                

        color_formatter = ColoredFormatter(self.COLOR_FORMAT)

        console = logging.StreamHandler()
        console.setFormatter(color_formatter)

        self.addHandler(console)
        return


logging.setLoggerClass(ColoredLogger)
```

Comment: How is that answering the question? What about the colors?

Comment: I did not try it yet; at first look it looks a little bit complicated at least for me; but I will give it a try anyway; thanks for all tips and advices!